# What is the name of this story about a psychopathic priest

Tags: story-identification, warhammer-40k

I recall reading a comic once that had a psychopathic priest/inquisitor from Warhammer 40k.
He had a fat, small assistant and was very zealous. It might have been set in Necromunda.
There were plague zombies and some shamans.

It finished with the fat assistant being lobotomised and turned into a servitor of some kind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found it! It is called The Redeemer. The overzealous Priest is called Klovis.